# JFrame issues in Java

Tags: java, jframe

Does anyone have any idea as to why I have to expand my JFrame and then shrink it back down to get my text and buttons to display? Here's an example of one of my JFrames I am having an issue with.

```
//method that develops 'WelcomeFrame'
public void WelcomeFrame()
{
  //creates new frame with 'choiceFrame' variable
  welcomeFrame = new JFrame("Welcome!");

  //sets 'welcomeFrame' to visible
  welcomeFrame.setVisible(true);

  //sets size of frame
  welcomeFrame.setSize(330,115);

  //frame will close when you hit close button
  welcomeFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  //displays frame in middle of page
  welcomeFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

  //initializes labels and what they will display
  instructions = new JLabel("<html>Welcome to Moe's Original BBQ Application!<br>"
     +"Please click CONTINUE to proceed to the home page!</html>");

  //creates new panel, hold all components and displays them on frame
  JPanel welcomePanel = new JPanel();

  //adds label to panel
  welcomePanel.add(instructions);

  //sets panel background to light gray
  welcomePanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

  //sets 'continueButton' background/foreground to light gray
  continueButton.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
  continueButton.setForeground(Color.darkGray);

  //adds button to panel
  welcomePanel.add(continueButton);     

  //adds panel to frame   
  welcomeFrame.add(welcomePanel);  
}
```

Thanks

Comment: So what's your actual issue? You want to resize the JFrame with the panel automatically?

Comment: no I have set the size of the frame in which I want it. Just when I run my program it shows up initially as a blank JFrame, when I expand it then shrink it back down to original size(330,115), it shows the text and button. I don't know why I have to expand and shrink it back down to get it to show my output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `setVisible()` before your `JFrame` is finished being set up, try calling `setVisible()` when your `JFrame` is finished being set up completely. `setVisible()` will call a repaint, and repaint will paint anything that's already been added and is currently visible (which for you at the point you call it nothing but the `JFrame` itself). Resizing the frame causes another repaint event to be queued, which by then more visible components have been added to and will now be painted.

Comment: NP, curious myself, is your JFrame being constructed on the EDT? I am thinking if it was that you wouldn't have seen this issue as the repaint request would have been executed after `WelcomeFrame()` finished.

Comment: Also don't forget to `pack()` your frame. Would probably have avoided your issue. From the API  `Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents. If the window and/or its owner are not yet displayable, both are made displayable before calculating the preferred size. The Window will be validated after the preferredSize is calculated.`

Comment: Technically, it has more to do with how the frame is marked for requiring laying out rather than requiring to be painted.  The window would be black if it wasn't been painted. Resizing invalidates the container hierarcy, requiring the contents to be re-laid out and then painting ;), but correct advice non-the-less

Comment: Yeah I was second guessing what I thought about it after I accepted, didn't make sense. I'll make a mental note to update this answer later.